# How to dynamically add new promise to the promises chain

Tags: javascript, promise

I want to create promises chain and then dynamically add as many promises to it as it's needed. These additions could be in some cycle with dynamic number of steps so that I can't use chain like .then().then().then... Code bellow works improperly but you'll get the idea. Result should be a console logged 3000, 4000, 5000 numbers in 3, 4 and 5 seconds consequently but actually doesn't work that way. Any ideas?

```
let launchChain = function(delay)
{
  return new Promise((resolve: Function, reject: Function) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(delay);
      resolve();
    }, delay)
  })
}

let chain = launchChain(3000);

chain.then(function () {
  return launchChain(4000);
})

chain.then(function () {
  return launchChain(5000);
})
```

Comment: `chain = chain.then ....`?

Comment: once it gets resolve, you cannot re-open it. You will have to do polling externally

Comment: Jaromanda X, it's done that way in the code itself. But it works improperly. Run it and you'll see )

Comment: Can you tell what exactly doesn't work properly for you with your provided code? Console logs "3000, 4000, 5000 numbers in 3, 4 and 5 seconds consequently" for me.

Comment: David, 5000 logs after 4000 in just one second not 5. It seems chain.then(function () {  return launchChain(4000); })

chain.then(function () {  return launchChain(5000);}) launched simultaneously

Answer (score 8):

So used [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and this [site](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/)

```js
var delays = [0, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000];

function workMyCollection(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(promise, item) {
    return promise.then(function() {
      return launchChain(item);
    });
    // uses this orignal promise to start the chaining.
  }, Promise.resolve());
}

function launchChain(delay) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(delay);
      resolve();
    }, delay);
  });
}

workMyCollection(delays);
```

[EDIT] : Another way

```js
var delays = [0, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000];
var currentPromise = Promise.resolve();

for (let i = 0; i < delays.length; i++) {
  // let makes i block scope .. var would not have done that
  currentPromise = currentPromise.then(function() {
    return launchChain(delays[i]);
  });
}

function launchChain(delay) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(delay);
      resolve();
    }, delay);
  });
}
```

Do let me know if this worked for you :)
thanks to this question I learned a lot!

Answer (score 3):

```
function run(delay){
    let chain = launchChain(delay);
    chain.then(function() {
        run(delay+1000);
    });
}


run(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks sinhavartika! It works! But I actually took example from here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce
and changed it a bit and now I use it in my project in the following way:

```
  /**
   * Runs promises from promise array in chained manner
   *
   * @param {array} arr - promise arr
   * @return {Object} promise object
   */
  function runPromiseInSequense(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((promiseChain, currentPromise) => {
      return promiseChain.then((chainedResult) => {
        return currentPromise(chainedResult)
          .then((res) => res)
      })
    }, Promise.resolve());
  }

  var promiseArr = [];

  function addToChain(delay)
  {
    promiseArr.push(function (delay) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(delay);
            resolve();
          }, delay)
      });
    }.bind(this, delay))
  }

  addToChain(1000);
  addToChain(2000);
  addToChain(3000);
  addToChain(4000);

  runPromiseInSequense(promiseArr);
```

Comment: What you are trying to do is not clear .. but if it works for you then if great!